# How to set this range border?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set the border that like this.

[image: what I want to achieve]

My code can't perform the effect like in the picture, the middle is empty (without border) with this border thickness.

The range is `A4:B30`.

```
With Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(row, 2))' row is second last row
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlHairline
End With
```

How can I get a thin middle border between the interior cells of my range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cosmetic changes, always try recording macro and reading the code. That's the best way. :)

```
Sub testBorders()

With Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(30, 2)).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
'/(xlEdgeRight) sets the border only to right most cells
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlMedium '/ as per your pic you are looking for medium weight.
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: still three lines missing . top , left , bottom(above overall that line)

Comment: great.. now you know what to do and how to do it. :) Get cracking... if stuck use the macro recorder.

Comment: i add 3 more three to add the top,left,bottom

Comment: You could use bordersaround  method